# Kick reliably in Dark Souls

Tags: dark-souls

Is there a setting to adjust the sensitivity of kicking or leap attack?
I'm using an XBOX controller on the PC.
I'm using a mace.  I know it is left stick forward + RB (or RT for leap attack).  I'm pressing them at exactly the same time.
I can get it to happen about 25% of the time while I'm just practicing in an open area with no enemies.  I can't seem to figure this out, so there is no way I can reliably do it in combat.

To be clear: during the other 75% of the time (when I fail to pull off the move(s)) I get a step forward and light attack or heavy attack.  So my buttons and stick are working on the controller.  This appears to be strictly a timing issue.

Comment: Same issue here. In fact, the only times when I can reliably kick is when I absolutely don't need it and when it will probably get me killed.

Comment: That's a good question. Sometimes I do attacks too instead of kicks because the window in which you have to press the buttons is so small. Maybe you could try pressing the attack button a bit sooner and push the stick forward very fast. That's how I do it and I get a kick about 90% of the time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is absolutely possible to get comfortable at the kick and jump attack but there is no setting to make it easier.

I am unsure of the frame data for kicking, but the active frame window for parrying (one of the most advanced combat maneuvers) is from 6 to 8 frames, I assume it is the same for kicking.

That being said, the game runs at ~30 fps giving you a whole 1/5 of a second to input the commands together.

The 'forward' command is inputted at the top of the joystick gradiant meaning that you can press forward but it will not count towards the kick command until it hits 100%. Because of this, most times that I fail the kick it is because the forward command was too late. I have found it is easiest to input the rb when I hear the 'click' sound of the joystick hitting its cage, in an effort to delay the forward command until I know it is actually being [inputted](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30684/inputted-or-input).

Comment: This helped quite a bit.  After practicing for a while, I can get them about 75% of the time.  Enough I can use them in combat.  I didn't realize it was the top of the stick's motion.